# How to get local-notification without Apns for ios in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I searched some notification library for react-native.

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

This works well for Android but it requires Apns for ios

I would like to find some libraries that doen not require Apns and simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is no avoiding using [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) for remote push notifications.

In order to receive data in certain scenarios, such as having your app running in the background, phone being offline and later receiving a notification once it is back online, your device must have a unique app-specific device token generated by Apple. You can then use a service such as [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) or [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) to deliver the notification to clients.

Also, for Android, you will need to use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to generate the device token.

You can, for testing purposes, you can use [react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)' `PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule` to create a dummy local notification.

Here is a good tutorial for setting up remote push notifications with APNS and FCM: https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/.